# Angular 2 attr.disabled not behaving as expected

Tags: angular, checkbox

I have a list of items to display and alongside each item there is a checkbox. I have a condition statement to check whether each item's checkbox should be disabled or enabled. For some unclear reason every checkbox in my list is disabled and i am not sure if it is how i set up the [attr.disabled] or an error in my condition statement.

Here is my html:

```
 <input class="form-control" [attr.disabled]="disabled == true ? true : null"
     type="checkbox"[checked]="item.status" (click)="itemChecked($event, item)" />
```

In my component:

```
private disabled: boolean;

for( let item of items){
if (item.id == Status.required) {
                item.status = true;
                this.disabled= true;
            } else if (item.id != Status.required && item.list.length > 0) {
                item.status = item.id == Status.checked
                this.disabled= false;
            } else {
                item.status = item.id == Status.unchecked;
                this.disabled= false;
            }
    }
```

Currently in my list regardless of the status of my item, all check boxes are disabled and not sure why.

Comment: Are you using this code in ngFor ?

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma yes

Comment: You are using this.disabled=true/false in component. Keep item.disabled=true/false in component. Your code is keeping only one copy of disabled for the component. You need to keep disabled for each item type object

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma so are you saying because i have declared this.disabled that it is overriding in the html based on last item?

Comment: yes thats exactly what i m saying

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @NanditaAroraSharma I was able to realize that this.disabled was been overridden every time a list item's status changed and thus reflecting the last status of the list and applying it to all the items. I updated my `[attr.disabled] = "item.id == 1 ? true : null"` and now only the items that really should be disabled are disabled.

Answer (score 3):

try this one `[disabled]`

```
<input class="form-control" [disabled]="disabled == true ? true : null"
 type="checkbox"[checked]="item.status" (click)="itemChecked($event, item)" />
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<input class="form-control" [ngClass]="{'disableDiv': disabled  === true}" 
     type="checkbox"[checked]="item.status" (click)="itemChecked($event, item)" />
```

in css

```
.disableDiv {
        pointer-events: none;
    }
```